# Why am I able to change the array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

I was studying for  my exam then ı saw this on the net.My question is that are not the arrays are basically constant pointers in c (so that there were an error ) ? At first I wanted to get an error about this "b+=2" but there was none.

```
int  func (  int  b[])
{

    b +=2;
    printf("%d",*b);
}

int main()
{

  int arr[]={1,2,3,4};
  func(arr);

 return 0;
}
```

( output of this program is 3 btw)

Comment: When used as a parameter `int  b[]` means `int *b`. It's not an array. (`sizeof(b)` will even return `sizeof(int*)`.)

Comment: @ikegami oh is it  . thanks

Comment: When used as function parameters, arrays get converted to pointers, aka they decay to pointers.

Comment: with `b += 2` you simply change address value in b from first element of an array to the third one which is `3`, so the code is legal and there is no error

Comment: @oguzhanarslan Be sure to understand that `int x[10];` as a variable declaration does not behave the same as `int x[10]` as a function parameter. What people are saying about `b` being a pointer here is true to some extent *for function parameters*. It is not true, in general, that arrays *are* pointers. Arrays and pointers are distinct types of objects.

Comment: Try `int arr[]={4,3,2,1};` and you'll see a result that should explain more.

Comment: Tip: You should use `void` for a function that doesn't return anything. You have undefined behaviour.

Comment: Arrays are not "basically constant pointers", this is a common misconception. You can take the address of an array or elements of it,  just as for any variable

Comment: @ikegami it's not undefined unless the caller tries to use the return value, in C.  (in C++ it is undefined to omit the return statement)

Comment: @M.M, Thanks for the correction. I wasn't sure. (I also meant to say "I think it's undefined behaviour".) I also didn't noticed it was tagged both C and C++ (a no-no!), which I'm not really familiar with

Comment: @ikegami you are not wrong but my compiler handles that.

Comment: It does today, maybe. Are you sure. Did you blink? It might not work the next time you run the program. Well, if it was undefined behaviour, but M.M said it's not in C. Either way, it'll confuse your readers, and it warns. (You are enabling and heading warnings, right?)

Comment: @ikegami I see. I will be careful next time. Generally, I do not write such a code but just for the question ı did not care it much .

Comment: The language `C` and the language `C++` are two different languages.  Please make a choice and remove the other `tag`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> are not the arrays are basically constant pointers in c

No, they are not. Arrays are contiguous sequences of objects. Pointers are objects that refer to another object by storing the memory address.

> Why am I able to change the array
>
> ```
> b +=2;
> ```

`b` is not an array. `b` is a pointer. Initially, you pass a pointer to the first element of the array `arr`. Adding 1 to a pointer changes it to point to a successive element of the array. Adding 2 changes it to point to second successive element. Starting from the first element, the second successive element is the one at the index 2, which in this case has the value 3. This pointer arithmetic is why pointers can be used to iterate array elements.

> But it's declared using syntax that's normally associated with arrays

Function arguments cannot be arrays. You can declare the argument to be an array, but that declaration is *adjusted* to be a pointer to an element of the array. These two function declarations are semantically identical:

```
int  func (  int  b[]); // the adjusted type is int*
int  func (  int *b  );
```

Both of them declare a function whose argument is a pointer to `int`. This adjustment does not imply that arrays are pointers. This adjustment is complementary to the rule that the array implicitly converts into pointer to first element - this conversion is called decaying.

Note that argument declaration is the only case where this adjustment occurs. For example in variable declaration:

```
int arr[]={1,2,3,4}; // the type is int[4]; not int*
                     // the length is deduced from the initialiser
int *ptr;            // different type
```

Also note that the adjustment occurs only at the "top" level of compound types. These declarations are different:

```
int  funcA (  int (*b)[4]); // pointer to array
int  funcB (  int **b    ); // pointer to pointer
```

---

P.S. You've declared the function to return `int`, but have failed to provide a return statement. Doing so in C++ results in undefined behaviour of the program.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays decay to pointers to their first element when passed to functions. Hence the function is equivalent to

```
int  func (  int*  b)
{

    b +=2;
    printf("%d",*b);
}
```

The pointer is advanced by 2 and then the element at that position is printed. For the constness consider that parameters are passed by value. Ie `b` is a copy. You cannot do

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3,4};
arr+=2;
```

But you can do

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3,4};
int* p = arr;
p += 2;  // p now points to the third element
```

For the sake of completeness, `main` could be written as

```
 int main()
{

  int arr[]={1,2,3,4};
  func(&arr[0]);

 return 0;
}
```

Actually it is uncommon to write `&arr[0]` when passing arrays to functions, but this is just to illustrate what happens.

Comment: @ikegami no i didnt miss the point of the question. I presented a different way to write the same

Comment: @ikegami it works because arrays decay to pointers to their first element when passed to functions. Isnt this explaining what happens?

Comment: Sorry, misread. Merely a poor explanation.

Comment: @ikegami i'd be happy to get a suggestion for improvement. Whats else is there to say?

Comment: I,actually, asking about the fact that  is that arrays are constant pointers so that we cannot change them(but ın the function ı could)

Comment: @oguzhanarslan yeah just realized that I missed that part of the question

Comment: This does miss the mark a little.  The OP's main confusion is they think arrays are constant pointers.  This IMHO doesn't do a good job about addressing that misunderstanding.

Comment: Ok, I put my finger on the problem. You got cause an effect backwards. Arrays arguments degrade to pointers because a paramater of `int b[]` is equivalent to `int *b`, not the other way around

Comment: @oguzhanarslan see edit

Comment: @NathanOliver yeah I really missed that completely first, but tried to address it now

Comment: @ikegami when a is equivalent to b then b is equivalent to a. I really understand what you are picking at

Comment: I said "a causes b" doesn't mean "b causes a"

Comment: @ikegami your last comment: " Arrays arguments degrade to pointers because a paramater of int b[] **is equivalent** to int *b, not the other way around"

Comment: a = array arguments degrade to pointers

Comment: b = a parameter of `int b[]` is equivalent to `int *b`

Comment: The OP asked why `int b[]` is acting as `int *b`, and you say it's because array arguments degrade into points. That's not the reason at all. So 1) What you said it false (You got cause and effect backwards), and 2) you didn't give an answer (you didn't provide the reason they're equivalent)

Comment: If you ask me there's no real cause and effect here. So in my opinion `(int b[] <=> int *b) <=> arrays decay to pointers` and everyone is right. :)

Comment: @ikegami perhaps you missed the point of the question. It is about why `b += 2;` is not an error because "arrays are basically constant pointers in c" (OPs words). Whether `int *` or `int []` is the cause or the effect and that arrays decay to pointers is not what the question is about but I felt it is relevant enough to leave it in

Comment: I have absolutely no problem with the decaying being mentioned. I do agree it's a good thing to mention.

Answer (score 1):

When declaring a parameter, `int b[]` means `int *b`. It's not an array. In fact, `sizeof b` will even return `sizeof int *`.

From the C spec,

> A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of *type*’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘qualified pointer to *type*’’,  where  the  type  qualifiers  (if  any)  are  those  specified  within  the `[` and `]` of  the array  type  derivation.   If  the  keyword `static` also  appears  within  the `[` and `]` of  the array  type  derivation,  then  for  each  call  to  the  function,  the  value  of  the  corresponding actual argument shall provide access to the first element of an array with at least as many elements as specified by the size expression.

---

This leaves you with code passing an array to a function requiring a pointer, and that's perfectly fine. In such circumstances, the array will *degrade* into a pointer to its first element. It's as if

```
func(arr)
```

was

```
func(&(arr[0]))
```

Answer (score -4):

Hi Buddy you are very right at your position that arrays are constant pointers but while passing the address to the function the modification is seen only in the pointer variable b , not arr . This is because b is local to the function.

If the print statement would have been in the main() function as:

```
printf("%d",arr[0]);
```

or

```
printf("%d",*arr);
```

output would have been 1 . Just because the increment has affected the local value but not the real one.
Hope it helps!!

Comment: *Hi Buddy you are very right at your position that arrays are constant pointers* No, no no.  **ARRAYS ARE NOT POINTERS**

Comment: *"very right at your position that arrays are constant pointers"* That's not correct at all and a common myth that causes a lot of confusion for new programmers.